# Notice when removing widget

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I'm trying to customize itheme's Exchange e-commerce plugin. I'd like to add a catalogue ability - removing add to cart and buy now buttons. Since in exchange those buttons are created using their 'superwidget', I thought that the easiest way to remove those buttons is by removing the superwidget. So i created a function:

```
if(!function_exists('exchange_catalogue')){
    function exchange_catalogue(){
        unregister_widget( 'IT_Exchange_Super_Widget' );
    }
}

add_filter( 'widgets_init', 'exchange_catalogue');
```

But I get:

```
Notice: Undefined index: IT_Exchange_Super_Widget in /wp-includes/widgets.php on line 1356
```

I checked if there is such registered widget:

```
$widgets = array_keys( $GLOBALS['wp_widget_factory']->widgets );
print '<pre>$widgets = ' . esc_html( var_export( $widgets, TRUE ) ) . '</pre>';
```

just added that to the function above, and the widget is there (listed)

```
$widgets = array (
...
 26 => 'IT_Exchange_Super_Widget',
)
```

So if it exists, and my function removes it, why am I getting this notice??

Oh, and I am aware that there is an option for this, but only if you buy their expansion for ~$200, that will add an add on...

EDIT:

I tried with this:

```
    if (isset( $GLOBALS['wp_widget_factory']->widgets['IT_Exchange_Super_Widget'] )) {
        unset( $GLOBALS['wp_widget_factory']->widgets['IT_Exchange_Super_Widget'] );
    }
```

And with

```
    if (isset( $GLOBALS['wp_widget_factory']->widgets['IT_Exchange_Super_Widget'] )) {
        unregister_widget( 'IT_Exchange_Super_Widget' );
    }
```

But still am getting the notice.

Comment: maybe your function runs twice. According to this article http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_widget you should use `add_action`

Comment: Tried with add_action, still get the notice. The thing is that when I check with 'is_active_widget()', nothing happens...

Comment: I tried to see if it's set, and it is. With `isset( $GLOBALS['wp_widget_factory']->widgets['IT_Exchange_Super_Widget'] )`, but still I am getting this notice...

Comment: try `unset()` instead

Comment: No luck, still get the notice.

Comment: What is on line 1356 of that file? Could be the theme is still trying to load the widget.

Comment: `$widget_obj = $wp_widget_factory->widgets[$widget];` From the function that is called `the_widget`.

Comment: try `add_filter( 'widgets_init', 'exchange_catalogue', 99);` So it can load first and then be removed. Must be something in the sequence of commands. Or find where it is `set` in the theme files.

Comment: Still nothing. It seems like it removes it, but the plugin still tries to load it, and maybe there's the error.

Comment: It is not an error, it is a notice, things should work fine.

Comment: Well, things are working, and the widget is gone, but the notice is there, and it's kinda annoying :D

Comment: Can I set the array that holds the widget to an empty array so that when the plugin tries to load it, it will load empty array, and won't display a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer! :D

I just put

```
if(!function_exists('exchange_catalogue')){
    function exchange_catalogue(){
       if (isset( $GLOBALS['wp_widget_factory'])) {
           $GLOBALS['wp_widget_factory']->widgets['IT_Exchange_Super_Widget'] = null;
       }
    }
}
```

This way the widget is set, but it's nothing. So it's not showing :D Simple fix if you want catalog ability for exchange shop :)